# Why are these two objects null?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing an Android app and two buttons ("btnGPSShowLocation" and "button")  that I am using are null. I've instantiated them both so I don't know why they are null. Here is my code:

```
public class AndroidLocationActivity extends Activity {
Button btnGPSShowLocation;
Button button;


AppLocationService appLocationService;
private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 2; //2 minutes
Handler mHandler = new Handler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
            AndroidLocationActivity.this);

    btnGPSShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGPSShowLocation);

    btnGPSShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Location gpsLocation = appLocationService
                    .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (gpsLocation != null) {
                double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Mobile Location (GPS): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                                + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                showSettingsAlert("GPS");
            }

        }
    });

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("locationActivity"));
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the XML that may be relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="it226.myapplicationit226androidapp.AndroidLocationActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_gps">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Location\n(GPS)"
    android:id="@+id/btnGPSShowLocation"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nextgps"
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="106dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: here is the logcat

```
> 04-27 23:34:30.525 18310-18310/it226.myapplicationit226androidapp
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: it226.myapplicationit226androidapp, PID: 18310
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{it226.myapplicationit226androidapp/it226.myapplicationit226androidapp.AndroidLocationActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at
> it226.myapplicationit226androidapp.AndroidLocationActivity.onCreate(AndroidLocationActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                         at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>  
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post stracktrace !

Comment: Post logcat showing null object error

Comment: can you confirm it is `activity_main.xml` that contains the buttons ?

Comment: Is this xml file name activity_main

Comment: Why are you adding `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_gps"`. Try removing that as well

Comment: that was it....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_gps"`

> This attribute set on the root element of a layout that 'ed by another layout. This allows you to point to one of the layouts which includes this layout, and at designtime this included layout will be rendered with the outer layout surrounding it.

See here for [reference](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes)

Comment: FWIW, this is not the crash problem as the tools namespace only applies at design time, not at runtime where the problem occurs.

Comment: @laalto Yes that's so. Appreciate your words !